# BufferUnderflowException while querying OrientDB using OrientDB studio

Tags: orientdb

BufferUnderflowException thrown while executing the below query.

```
SELECT
FROM
(
match { class: a, AS: a }
.out('aTob') { AS: b, WHERE: (field1 is defined and field1 = true) }
.out('bToC') { WHERE: (field2 = 'XYZ'), AS: c }
return a
)
```

This query works fine when I add a LIMIT of 121 records.
If I add a limit of 122 or run the query without a limit, it throws "BufferUnderflowException"

Comment: Hi, what version are you using? Thx